# R - tryCatch warning message being written to data

Tags: r, error-handling

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I'm trying to write my own 'impute' function in R with a tryCatch statement which:
1. outputs a warning/error message containing the function name so I can debug easier. 
2. Raises a warning if the function runs ok but doesn't impute all the missing values.

```
ImputeVariables <- function(impute.var, impute.values, 
                        filter.var){
# function to impute values. 
# impute.var = variables with NAs
# impute.values = the missing value(s) to replace NAs, value labesl are levels
# filter.var = the variables to filter on. 
# filter.levels = the categories of filter.var
tryCatch({
    filter.levels <- names(impute.values)
    # Validation
    stopifnot(class(impute.var) == class(impute.values), 
             length(impute.values) > 0,
             sum(is.na(impute.values)) == 0)
    # Impute values
    for(level in filter.levels){
        impute.var[which(filter.var == level & is.na(impute.var))] <- 
            impute.values[level]
    }
    # Check if all NAs removed.  Throw warning if not. 
    if(sum(is.na(impute.var)) > 0){
        warning("Not all NAs removed")
    }
    # Return values
    return(impute.var)

}, 
    error = function(err) print(paste0("ImputeValues: ",err)),
    warning = function(war) print(paste0("ImputeValues: ",war))
)
}
```

`impute.var` and `filter.var` are vectors taken from a data.frame (they are vectors of Ages and Titles (e.g. 'Mr', 'Mrs')
`impute.values` is a vector of the same type as `impute.var` but with labels taken from `filter.var` (i.e. is of the form `c('Mr' = 30, 'Mrs' = 25...)`)

**The problem**

To check if my validation was working I supplied the function with a named vector of NAs, thusly:

```
ages <-   c(34, 22, NA, 17, 38, NA)
titles <- c("Mr", "Mr", "Mr", "Mrs", "Mrs", "Mrs")
ages.values <- c("Mr" = NA, "Mrs" = NA)

ages.new <- ImputeVariables(ages, ages.values, titles)

print(ages.new)
```

But it outputs the following:

```
 "ImputeValues: Error: class(impute.var) == class(impute.values) is not TRUE\n"
 "ImputeValues: Error: class(impute.var) == class(impute.values) is not TRUE\n"
```

The two lines are due to the function printing the `ages.new` vector and the following print statement printing `ages.new` (why?)

If I comment out the validation (the `stopifnot` function) then I just get:

```
"ImputeValues: simpleWarning in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): Not all NAs removed\n"
```

**What I'm asking**

1. Why does the tryCatch block behave this way?
2. Is my validation and error handling strategy optimal (obviously without the bug)?

Many thanks for your time.

Rob

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Oliver.

The working code is now:

```
 ImputeVariables <- function(impute.var, impute.values, 
                        filter.var){
# function to impute values. 
# impute.var = variables with NAs
# impute.values = the missing value(s) to replace NAs, value labesl are levels
# filter.var = the variables to filter on. 
# filter.levels = the categories of filter.var
tryCatch({
    filter.levels <- names(impute.values)
    # Validation
    stopifnot(class(impute.var) == class(impute.values), 
             length(impute.values) > 0,
             sum(is.na(impute.values)) == 0)
    # Impute values
    for(level in filter.levels){
        impute.var[which(filter.var == level & is.na(impute.var))] <- 
            impute.values[level]
    }
    # Check if all NAs removed.  Throw warning if not. 
    if(sum(is.na(impute.var)) > 0){
        warning("Not all NAs removed")
    }
    # Return values
    return(impute.var)

}, 
    error = function(err) stop(paste0("ImputeValues: ",err)),
    warning = function(war) {
        message(paste0("ImputeValues: ",war))
        return(impute.var)}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially two different problems. The first problem is that print statements within a function do not print to the terminal, they print to the scope of the function. As an example:

```
> foo <- function(){
     print("bar")
  }
> foo()
[1] "bar"
```

It didn't print "bar" to your screen, it printed it to the function scope and then returned it. The reason it returned it was that it was the last value printed to the function scope, and so (lacking an explicit return() call) is the best candidate for what to return.

So, your code is (in sequence):

1. Throwing an error;
2. Not treating that error normally, but instead passing it into tryCatch's error handler, where it is printed;
3. Because it is the last thing printed within the function scope, since the return() statement is never hit due to the error, treating it as the return value from the function.

If you really want to continue processing the input values even if the stopifnot() conditions are met, you don't want a stopifnot(): however you structure that it's likely to prevent the return() call from running and cause weirdness. What I'd suggest is instead moving the conditional checks currently in stopifnot() outside the tryCatch, and sticking them in a series of if() statements that throw warnings (not errors) if they don't match up. tryCatch isn't really necessary in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the information regarding the printing.  I hadn't realised that. 

What I want is two different things:

1. If the `stopifnot` fails, then the function stops with an error message.  
2. If the function runs but leaves some values un-imputed then a warning is produced. 

i.e. I don't want the function to continue if the `stopifnots` fail.

Comment: Okay! Does the answer help? If not: what two different things?

Comment: Sorry, I keep pressing enter before finishing the comment.

Comment: Gotcha. Then, why the tryCatch at all? If stopifnot fails, it will stop with an error message. If not all NAs are removed, it will throw a warning. If the intent of the tryCatch is to control what the error messages say, well, replace your first print() with error() and your second with warning().

Comment: OK, so what you're saying is the tryCatch is redundant unless I want to control what the message says.   
I don't follow what you're saying about the print statements though. 
If I make the replacement: 
`error = function(err) print(paste0("ImputeValues: ", err))`

`error = function(err) error(paste0("ImputeValues: ", err))`

I just get an error saying `could not find function "error"

Comment: Ack; "stop", sorry. This is R, so of course errors are handled by a function called !error :/. Yep, the tryCatch is redundant unless you want to control the message; if you DO want to control the message, warning() or stop() are the appropriate calls, not print().

Comment: Thanks for your help.  You've explained everything.